# Why maximum times, my NMEA HDOP value coming empty even outside?

Tags: android, gps, nmea

In Android, I have implemented `NMEAListener` using `onNMEAReceived()` method. In this I am getting **GPGGA** string as follows:

```
GPGGA,235942.000,2245.0750,N,07551.9900,E,0,0,,209.4,M,-59.4,M,,*67
```

But in this, maximum times even outside under open sky, I am getting *HDOP (token[8])* value i.e. accuracy as empty like above. 
So, can anyone please help me with the condition that when and why values of HDOP that shows blank.

Comment: What does HDOP mean?

Comment: You have no fix and the GPS chooses to send an empty value for HDOP.

Comment: Thanks Mikas, but how to handle this type of conditions.  I have applied empty condition

Comment: @greenapps: hdop is accurary

Comment: What does it stand for was the question.

Comment: @greenapps: Horizontal dilution of precision (HDOP)